# MVC: should i add and implement touch gestures in the View Controller or my custom subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I have this custom subclass of `UIView`, called `productCardView`, which is pretty simple and has some `UIImageView`s and `UILabel`s as it's subviews. I add the subviews and set them up the `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method and everything sits nicely.

In my view controller I get some data from a remote server and so populate the `productCardView`s that should be seen. the purpose is when the user taps on each of these cards the program goes to a target url(a `NSURL` property of each card).

**THE QUESTION IS** according to basics of MVC, should I add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view, inside my implementation of the `productCardView` or in my view controller? 
If I am to add it in the view controller, Basically I would put the appropriate code in the `viewDidLoad` method, where I create instances of cards, but in case I should implement it in the View itself, **where** should I put the code? (in `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether the tap is on the card or on the view controller you should be loading the url from the view controller.

So, that means either...

1. Card feels the tap and calls a function in its delegate (the view controller) that then loads a URL.

or

2. Tap gesture recogniser (in the view controller) gets the tap from the card and open the URL.

If the card is a control used in several places (or if you have several on the screen) you might be better making the `productCardView` a subclass of `UIControl` instead of `UIView`. (`UIButton`, `UISlider`, etc... are all subclasses of `UIControl`).

There isn't much you need to change but you can do something like...

```
[productCardView addTarget:self action:@selector(cardTapped:) event:UITouchUpInside];
```

just like a button.

You then handle the touch in the card view and `trigger` the action for the event `UITouchUpInside`.

Comment: thanks a lot, as I have several of these cards on my view controller I made it a subclass of `UIControl` and used the target/action.